# Link only answers - why not?

Tags: discussion, moderation, link-only-answers, external-links

For removal of "link only answers" the reason is given that if link changes the answers become invalid.

I have a few points here:

1. There are other software changes which make answers or both questions and answers invalid.
2. Sometimes a link is the best solution and it may not be possible to recreate the whole code in answers. Everything is not as simple as a plaintext file.
3. When someone is asking a question they are not asking for a "plain text" solution here and now. Anything that can help them is a solution, including a link.
4. If a link is invalid, it can be flagged and removed at any point. It would require same amount of effort as flagging and moderation to remove it in first place.

Given the point it would be nice to have Stack Overflow be more accommodating and solution oriented than hygiene conscious and limited in its scope to help solve problems for its users.

Just as "no AI answers" was the first response to AI based answers, but now a more accepting [OverflowAI](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/27/announcing-overflowai/) is being introduced as a solution, a similar "link only answers" model will be a welcome change.

Comment: this assumption is incorrect: _"It would require same amount of effort as flagging and moderation to remove it in first place."_ Allowing removal of only links that became obsolete would mean site users need to re-check the link many many tmes every tme they see it - possbly even for years, before it dies. Compared to this, removal at the first sight takes much less efforts. As for software changes, these don't make neither answers nor questions invalid, but instead merely narrow their area of applicability to the context of specific software versions

Comment: Have you read about [answers in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)? That manual is still applicable: if question is asking for a link (for example to obscure documentation), link is a valid answer. Otherwise your link simply doesn't provide an answer to the question asked. And if you want to help OP to solve their problem themselves: provide your link in a comment, and ask them to write proper answer once they solved problem with your help.

Comment: Not to be confused with [our princess is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-too-intrusive/1974#1974).

Comment: *"a similar "link only answers" model will be a welcome change"* - your opinion. Not a fact. If you want links, Google or Bing has them. Stack Overflow is a place for *good* answers, great answers if at all possible. Good answers require context in the form of an explanation, great answers leave nothing to the imagination.

Answer (score 13):

1. That's why it's important to give the version numbers of software which is used in a question/answer. People can check whether the answers apply to their environment.
2. Link *only* answers are what get removed. You can provide a link as a supplement.
3. Answers should stay useful into the future.
4. As gnat said: who is going to check the link?